# Django's --fake-initial doesn't work when migrating with existing tables

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am migrating a project from Django 1.1 to Django 3.0 I am done with the project. When I am dumping the production dump to my local in the newly converted project I get `"Table already exists"`.

Here's what I am doing.

```
mysql> create database xyx;

docker exec -i <container-hash> mysql -u<user> -p<password> xyx < dbdump.sql
```

then I run the migrate, as I have had to do some changes to the previously given models.

```
./manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

this is the output I get

```
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'city' already exists")
```

So, what to do ?

Comment: Probably table one or more tables are created not with initial migrations?  `--fake-initial` is only taken into account if the migration file has initial=True in migration class.

Comment: I totally didn't understand what that line meant when I read the documentation. So do you have a solution for this particular thing?

Comment: Take a look on your migrations - the first one do have attribute `initial` set to `True`. This one will be skipped, but if you have next migrations that creats `City` model without this attribute - Django will not skip it and raise an error. I think the solution you'll end up is to manually change migrations by removing table creations from all not-initial one's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright boys and girls, here's the approach I followed to solve this problem.

I dumped the entire database.

```
docker exec -i <container-hash> mysql -u<username> -p<password> <dbname> < dump.sql
```

Now I listed all the migrations I made using

```
./manage.py showmigrations <app-name>
```

This will give me the list of all the migrations I have applied, now from inspecting the migrations, I realized that from the 7th migration to the 30th migration I had done my changes.

Here's the tedious part which any sys admin can write a script to do in less than 4 lines of bash script. You can generate the raw SQL of any migration with this command.

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate <app-name> <migration-name> > changes-i-made.sql
```

Now that I have created my `changes-i-made.sql` file I'll need to run this script 22 more times but with `>>` otherwise everytime you run the command with a single `>` it will keep overwriting your changes file.

Now once all of your migration changes are recorded inside a file, open up your sql shell connect to the database and start pasting the changes or do some sql magic to pick all the changes directly from the file.

Once you're done go ahead and fake all the migrations, cause you don't need Django to do them you already did.

```
./manage.py migrate --fake
```

and then login to your production instance and get ready to fuck with your senior team lead who said you couldn't do it.

I just checked to see if this approach is working and the future migrations will be working, so I created one and everything works like a breeze.